# Configure Resource Scheduler across system manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I've followed this article on [How to easily configure Resource Scheduler across your Organization with Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-easily-configure-resource-scheduler-across-your-organization-with-systems-manager-quick-setup/)

I've added the tag to my EC2 instance as requested STOP / START doesn't work.

To create **ResourceScheduler** i've to **use** a **specific account** for that ( *AWS_ACCOUNT_test1* ) from there different **OU** with different user associate to it .

My EC2 instance are running below  **OU=Infra USERS=Test2**
I've **added** [AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore.html) to the user **Test2** and **AWS_ACCOUNT_test1**

Do you have an idea of anything I might have forgotten?

I searched on the internet before coming to ask you